# Неоднозначное (для меня) поведение QTcpSocket, возможная утечка

Tags: c++, qt

Метод класса (слот) получает на вход начальный адрес и количество хостов подсети, далее в цикле динамически создается сокет производится соединение сигналов

```
connected
statecchanged
error
```

далее вызывается

```
connectToHost.
```

В слоте коннект пытаюсь записать в сокет мой запрос и если запись успешна присоединяю сигнал

```
readyread
```

и в слоте

```
readyread
```

читаю ответ отправляю сигнал в основной класс где парсится ответ и далее

```
_pSocket->disconnectFromHost();
_pSocket->deleteLater();
```

Соответственно в слотах `error` и `statechanged` при условии изменения состояния на дисконект я также удаляю сокет. Сокет отправитель определяю через `sender`

```
QTcpSocket* _pSocket = qobject_cast<QTcpSocket*>(sender());
```

Собственно вопрос - почему в диспетчере задач растет используемая память (за пару дней плюс 10Мб)?

Answer (score 2):

Удаление объектов Qt следует выполнять при помощи метода `deleteLater()`
Каждому объекту следует задавать родительский объект, тогда удаление произойдет автоматически, при удалении родителя.

Искать утечки памяти при помощи диспетчера задач - не совсем корректно. Если менеджер памяти решит в целях оптимизации работы довыделить память, он это сделает, а вы решите что программа потекла.

Для поиска утечек памяти есть `Valgrind`, `DrMemory` и другие прекрасные инструменты.

Comment: родителя не могу, другой поток, удаляю deletelater, для какой цели он довыделяет? количество активных сокетов не меняется, причин для довыделения нет.

Comment: При выделении памяти под новый сокет ему приходит в голову выделить новые страницы, а не взять ранее выделенные. Ну, звезды так сошлись. Тем более, что у вас ресурсы из разных потоков выделяются.

Comment: но тем не менее ранее выделенное то должно же когда ни будь уменьшать счетчик объема показываемый в диспетчере?

Comment: Какой конкретно счетчик?

Comment: объем занятой памяти

Comment: Версия Windows у вас какая?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75603/discussion-between-dow-jhob-and-gbg).